# How to convert newline to \n in node/gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, newline

I have a JSON file that is more convenient to write with actual new lines but when reading that with gulp-data, it does not allow new lines, so I want to compile it to an appropriately formatted JSON file to read in.

I've delved a bit deeper and found gulp-replace and I replaced all \n with \n, but that also changes newlines that aren't in strings in the json. Is there a good way to only replace ones in strings?

Here's my code so far:

```
gulp.task('json', function(){
  gulp.src(['./content.json'])
    .pipe(replace('\n', '\\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('json'));
});
```

Comment: You'll increase the possibility of getting an answer If you edit your question to: **1**. show a snippet of your source `.json` **2**. show the desired `.json` output.

Comment: thanks, rob. I decided to not put longer stuff in json, so i dont care anymore

Comment: I think that's wise Florin, besides actual new lines in a JSON string are not valid - they need to be ` \n`. I think JSON was probably the wrong format to begin with (not end up with though!), given what you were trying to achieve.